# How to output a msg in a day/night

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'd like to salute my visitors with "Bonjour" or "Bonsoir", so with this script must output "Bonsoir" at 18h (6pm), and "Bonjour" before that time :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 today=new Date()
 if(today.getHours() < 0 && today.getHours() >= 18)
 {     
 document.getElementById('Bonjour').innerHTML='Test Bonsoir';
 }
</script>
```

```html
<span id="Bonjour">Bonjour</span>
```

Here is the live [code](http://location-voiture-agadir-pas-cher.fr/blog/) i use, as you see, the Js output in the span allways "Bonsoir" even if it a day or night.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: giving a quick read, think about that: how is it going to be less than zero **and** higher than 18 at the same time?

Comment: Umm math problems perhaps?  If you examine your own code carefully before you ask, then you wont end up asking silly questions like this.

Comment: @JK : Pls, illuminate us with your help, I see just your dark side!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be less than zero and greater than 18 at the same time.

Try ...

```
if(today.getHours() < 0 || today.getHours() >= 18)
```

**UPDATE**:

Tested ... working: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/b5m50ocs/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I test your code :
`if(today.getHours() < 0 || today.getHours() >= 18)`
But it dont output the test message : "Test Bonsoir"

Comment: Added a fiddle where it works ... the number is the `getHours()` value when executed.

Comment: yes it work in the 'jsFiddle' so I copy past your code in my website, but some thing stop it working !!!
have you any idea,
Thanks for all

Comment: This might be an issue of what your time is on the server versus client computer. Leave the code in the test in one time on the website to see what the hour is being returned ... it may not match what you expect.

Comment: i dont think so, but Thank you for your code who work perfectly...i'll try to put the code in the footer perhaps will work in my website.
Thanks again.